# java. Unique identifier for each visitor. How better generated?

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate a unique identifier (`uniqueID`) for each visitor my site. Which algorithm is better use for this? Have any ideas?

**Update:** small condition: do not use Session Id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be to store a [`UUID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) in the Session.

Answer (score 4):

How about just using the web container's Session ID?

See [`HttpSession.getId()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId%28%29)

Comment: And that's even easier than `UUID`. This option is preferable to my own unless you truly have to generate the value yourself, for some reason.

Comment: small condition: do not use Session Id.

Comment: In that case, go with picky's answer

Answer (score 0):

I usually use microsec time, but if two users somehow get on at the exact same time i add a random number to the end of it. (still a possibility for repeats, but very unlikely)